# Which queue does `wait()` suspended process goes into?

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

According to [javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/os-process-queues), ready and wait queue are different. But according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state#Ready) they are synonymous, in this context. Now I am more confused.

What I want to know is, when the parent process executes `wait(NULL)`, in which queue it gets enqueued?

What I think is, since it blocked (or suspended), it should go in waiting queue. If we consider process also as resources, then it is waiting for those "resources" to be released. But according to the book (galvin), it will go into ready state. Now if the parent is always loaded in main memory, and assigned all the resources, while its waiting for `wait(NULL)` to resume, then what book says makes sense. Otherwise, will it go into waiting queue?